# Creating an anchor tag that works with every item

Tags: react-router, anchor

What I want to do:

When I click on the image of one card, redirects to the item URL

What Seems to Be the catch?

The catch is that I have 3 different files with info that I need to connect

Note: I want to add an external URL, not a Link inside the page

I have the /data/projects.js:

```
const projects = [
  {
    id: 'a',
    name: 'YoLo ecommerce',
    desc: ' chlotes for women, created in React.js',
    img: Yolo,
  },
  {
    id: 'b',
    name: 'My Crypto Tracker',
    desc: 'An App to see the Crypto market. React.js/Chart.js',
    img: Trade,
  },
```

Note that maybe i have to insert the URL like an item

I have the components/projectItem.js:

```
export default function ProjectItem({
  img = ProjectImg,
  title = 'Project Name',
  desc = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
}) {
  return (
    <ProjectItemStyles>
      <Link to="/projects" className="projectItem__img">
        <img src={img} alt="project img" />
      </Link>
      <div className="projectItem__info">
        <Link to="#">
          <h3 className="projectItem__title">{title}</h3>
        </Link>
        <p className="projectItem__desc">{desc}</p>
      </div>
    </ProjectItemStyles>
  );
}
```

Note that here is where I think I have to put the right path to the project URL.

Then I have the proper pages/projects.js:

```
return (
    <>
      <ProjectStyle>
        <div className="container">
          <SectionTitle
            heading="Projects"
            subheading="some of my recent works"
          />
          <div className="projects__searchBar">
            <form>
              <input
                type="text"
                value={searchText}
                onChange={handleChange}
                placeholder="Project Name"
              />
              <MdSearch className="searchIcon" />
            </form>
          </div>
          <div className="projects__allItems">
            {projectsData.map((item) => (
              <ProjectItem
                key={item.id}
                title={item.name}
                desc={item.desc}
                img={item.img}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </ProjectStyle>
    </>
  );
}
```

I tried to add an anchor tag outside the `<ProjectItem>` but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all! A friend find the Solution:

/data/projects.js

```
const projects = [
  {
    id: uuidv4(),
    name: 'YoLo ecommerce',
    desc: ' chlotes for women, created in React.js',
    img: Yolo,
    link: 'https://yolocommerce.netlify.app',
  },
  {
    id: uuidv4(),
    name: 'My Crypto Tracker',
    desc: 'An App to see the Crypto market. React.js/Chart.js',
    img: Trade,
    link: 'https://crypto-trackerfederico.netlify.app',
  },
```

components/projectItem.js

```
export default function ProjectItem({
  img = ProjectImg,
  title = 'Project Name',
  desc = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
  link,
}) {
  return (
    <ProjectItemStyles>
      <a href={link}>
        <img src={img} alt="project img" />
        <div className="projectItem__info">
          <h3 className="projectItem__title">{title}</h3>
          <p className="projectItem__desc">{desc}</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </ProjectItemStyles>
  );
}
```

pages/project.js

```
  return (
    <>
      <ProjectStyle>
        <div className="container">
          <SectionTitle
            heading="Projects"
            subheading="some of my recent works"
          />
          <div className="projects__searchBar">
            <form>
              <input
                type="text"
                value={searchText}
                onChange={handleChange}
                placeholder="Project Name"
              />
              <MdSearch className="searchIcon" />
            </form>
          </div>
          <div className="projects__allItems">
            {projectsData.map((item) => (
              <ProjectItem
                key={item.id}
                title={item.name}
                desc={item.desc}
                img={item.img}
                link={item.link}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </ProjectStyle>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).